# Prove that there exists a vector $u ∈ W$ such that $u · v = 0$ and $u · u = 1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

> Let $v ∈ R^n$ such that $v · v = 1$ and let $W$ be a subspace of $R^n$
>   such that $dim(W) > 1$. Prove that there exists a vector $u ∈ W$ such
>   that $u · v = 0$ and $u · u = 1$.

I was told to find a unit vector $u ∈ W$ that is orthogonal to $proj_Wv$ and then show that $u · v = 0$.

I think the terminology is throwing me off. I know that having a unit vector ensures that $u · u$ will be $1$, but how can I be sure that this is orthogonal to the projection? Do I have to use the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: Is $v $ also in $W $? If not, the result as you have given it is not true. For example, take $W $ to be the $xy $plane in $R^3$, and $v=(1,1,1)/\sqrt {3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\dim(W)>1$ and $v\ne 0$ there exists $w\in W$ such that $w\ne rv$ for any scalar $r$. So $w-(w\cdot v)v\ne 0.$  Let $w'=w-(w\cdot v)v.$ Let $u=w'/\sqrt {w'\cdot w'}.\;$ Verify that $u\cdot u=1$ and $u\cdot v=0$.

This is  the Gram-Schmidt process applied to the two linearly independent vectors $w,v.$

Comment: Did you mean for any scalar $r$?

Comment: Yes. That was a typo.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I think you assume (correctly) that $v\in W $. The asker may not be aware of this as this is not given in their question.

Comment: I'm assuming so because I'm not sure it's possible if it isn't. This wasn't given, though.

Comment: @Any.It is not necessary that $v\in W.$ The 1-dimensional vector subspace  $<v> $ generated by $v$ does not include  all of $W$.   So $ w$  can be any member of $W$  \  $<v>$.

Comment: I don't think that will work. As you stated it, $u$ is just a scalar multiple of $w$. But why should $w\cdot v = 0$ be true in the first place?

Comment: @Bemte. I  had a major typo, which I have fixed. Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

Let $U$ be the linear span of $v$. Then $\mathbb R^n=U \oplus U^{\perp}$ and $\dim U^{\perp}=n-1$. We have $\dim W \ge 2$. Now show that

$ W \cap U^{\perp} \ne \{0\}$.

Each $u \in W \cap U^{\perp}$ with $u · u = 1$ works !

Comment: To add on your answer, we can use the fact $\dim{A\cup B} = \dim{A}+\dim{B}-\dim{A\cap B}$ to show that $W\cap U^\perp \neq \{0\}$